# How can I enable Cross-Domain-Origin using Undertow

Tags: java, php, linux, debian, cross-domain

I have created a web server to allow my website to access my game data via an API. My web Server looks like this (I am using `me.apachenick` framework)

```
public class WebServer {
    public static void initialize() {
        ServerController server = new ServerController("192.168.0.21", 8080, 8443);
        server.register(new APIVirtualHost());
        server.inititialize();
    }
}
```

My APIVirtualHost looks like this

```
public class APIVirtualHost extends AbstractVirtualHost {
    public static final String HOST_NAME = "XX.X.XX.XXX";

    public APIVirtualHost() {
        super(HOST_NAME);
        setDirectoryListingEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

An example route of displaying online players looks like this

```
@RouteManifest(template="/online/players", method="GET")
public class APIHighscoresRoute extends RouteHttpHandler<JadePreprocessor> {
    @Override
    public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
        Gson builder = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        JsonArray arr = new JsonArray();
        World.getPlayers().forEach(o -> {
            JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
            obj.addProperty("username", o.getUsername());
            arr.add(obj);
        });
        exchange.getResponseHeaders().put(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/html");
        exchange.getResponseSender().send(builder.toJson(arr));
    }
}
```

When I now run the web server (`WebServer.initialize()`) and goto `XX.X.XX.XX:8080/online/players` from my browser - this works fine! I am able to see all players in the world.

However, when I send a cURL request from PHP like so

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://XX.X.XX.XXX:8080/online/players');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8088);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
echo curl_getinfo($ch) . '<br/>';
echo curl_errno($ch) . '<br/>';
echo curl_error($ch) . '<br/>';
curl_close($ch);
```

I get this error:

> bool(false)
>   Array
> 7
> Failed to connect to XX.X.XX.XXX port 8088: Connection refused

Which tells me that Cross-Origin is not enabled on the requested resource. How can I enable cross-origin on my Java Web Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Undertow, to enable CORS you must download the CORS filter library.

Since this was simply a limitation to the way my web server works, I changed the angle and simple made it so the server requests the web server rather than the other way round.

Yes, this is a long way of doing it but it was the easiest way.

If anyone knows how to enable CORS with Undertow within my circumstance, I will alter the accepted answer.

Thanks again

Comment: could you provide some links, esp. to where exactly your 'according' comes from (Undertow documentation?) and the CORS filter library (did you mean https://github.com/Download/undertow-cors-filter ?)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not CORS problem, but your curl config. You're trying connect via 8088 port, but service is on 8080, change to (or remove from config, you already have it in CURLOPT_URL parameter):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8080);
```

Comment: I tried this before, sorry i did not mention it! It gives me the same error, connection refused